# Grails FindBy* with an inteface property

Tags: grails, grails-orm, findby

I have a class like

```
class Account {

    BigDecimal balance = 0
    SortedSet transactions

    AccountOwner owner

    static constraints = {
    }

    static hasMany = [transactions:Transaction]
}
```

when I try to query the Account like

```
def account = Account.findByOwner(user)
```

I get this error

```
| Failure:  testSave(br.com.fisgo.financial.AccountControllerTests)
|  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Cannot query [br.com.fisgo.financial.Account] on non-existent property: owner
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery.getValidProperty(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:706)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery.executeSubQueryInternal(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:644)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery.executeSubQuery(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:630)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery.executeQuery(SimpleMapQuery.groovy:63)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.query.Query.list(Query.java:486)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.invokeQuery(AbstractFindByFinder.java:34)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder$1.doInSession(AbstractFindByFinder.java:26)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:301)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:40)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.doInvokeInternal(AbstractFindByFinder.java:24)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:151)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:352)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:108)
    at br.com.fisgo.financial.AccountController.buyLead(AccountController.groovy:17)
    at br.com.fisgo.financial.AccountControllerTests.testSave(AccountControllerTests.groovy:92)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 5414ms
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in target\test-reports
```

Using this interface

```
package br.com.fisgo.financial;

public interface AccountOwner {

}
```

I'm using mocked object for testing

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your AccountOwner domain class?

Comment: package br.com.fisgo.financial;

public interface AccountOwner {

}
it's in a AccountOwner.java file

Answer (score 0):

Since findBy* are handled by GORM and GORM doesn't handle interfaces I don't think it's going to work.  Could you make AccountOwner an abstract class?